# If matrix B is more aligned to matrix A than C to A when flattened, are the matrix vector product By and Ay more aligned than Cy and Ay?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

Let A, B and C be matrices. When flattened, the angle between A and B is closer to 0 than A and C. When these matrices are multiplied by the same vector y, is the angle between vectors Ay and By closer to 0 than Ay and Cy? If so, is there a way to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: On another note, for some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that the more commonly used term for "flattening" is [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example, take $y = (1,0,\dots,0)^T$ and take $A,B,C$ to be the block-matrices
$$
A = I_{6 \times 6}, \quad B = \pmatrix{R_{\pi/2} \\ & I_{4 \times 4}}, \quad C = \pmatrix{R_{\pi/3} \\ & R_{\pi/3}\\ && R_{\pi/3}},
$$
where $R_\theta$ denotes the matrix of the rotation by angle $\theta$. When vectorized, each matrix forms a length $36$ vector with length $\sqrt{6}$. We see that the dot products are
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A)\cdot \operatorname{vec}(B) = 4 > \operatorname{vec}(A)\cdot \operatorname{vec}(C) = 3.
$$
So, $A,B$ are "more aligned" than $A$ and $C$. However, we find that $Ay,By,Cy$ are all unit vectors, and
$$
(Ay) \cdot (By) = 0 < (Ay) \cdot (Cy) = 1/2.
$$
So, $Ay$ and $By$ are "less aligned" than $Ay$ and $Cy$.